# jQuery: array function stops after first item

Tags: jquery, select, dynamic

I would like to use the following function to create a dropdown with the unique values of a column.

The function creates the dropdown but only shows the first value of the column there instead of all unique values from that column.

What is wrong or missing here?

```
function createDropdownFromColumn() {
    var arr = [];
    $("td:first").each(function() {
        if ($.inArray($(this).text(), arr) == -1)
            arr.push($(this).text());
    });

    // create select
    var select = $("<select />");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        $("<option>" + arr[i] + "</option>").appendTo(select);
    }

    // append select
    select.appendTo("body");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That selector probably only matches one single element, the first TD, and you're really looking for the `first-child` selector:

```
$("td:first-child").each(function() {...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your only getting one value because **you're only asking for the first matched `td` element**.

Your selector is:

```
"td:first"
```

Which, as per [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), retrieves only the first matched element. If you wanted all `td` elements that are first children of their respective `tr` elements, your selector would simply be:

```
"td:first-child"
```

See the documentation on [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) for further info.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to throw some debugging in there next time too if you're having problems like this.  For example, print the number of elements in your "arr" array would have pointed to the problem being that only one item was grabbed.

That would have pointed you back to your selector being the issue then checking out:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

the ":first" description being: "Selects the first matched element."

That jquery website is an amazing resource when coding websites.